# Organisational chart

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does anyone know which is the most optimal free JS library for a dynamic organisational chart where you can add and delete nodes like this:

[image: Orgchart]

Comment: Yes i see in google, i found some library like trent js , orgchart js, but but I'm looking for better

Comment: Your picture to show "add/delete nodes" functionality is lost.

Answer (score -1):

please check below html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/Treant.css">
<script src="https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/vendor/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/Treant.js"></script>
<script>
var simple_chart_config = {
    chart: {
        container: "#OrganiseChart-simple"
    },

    nodeStructure: {
        text: { name: "Parent node" },
        children: [
            {
                text: { name: "First child" }
            },
            {
                text: { name: "Second child" }
            }
        ]
    }
};
var config = {
    container: "#OrganiseChart-simple"
};

var parent_node = {
    text: { name: "Parent node" }
};

var first_child = {
    parent: parent_node,
    text: { name: "First child" }
};

var second_child = {
    parent: parent_node,
    text: { name: "Second child" }
};

var simple_chart_config = [
    config, parent_node,
        first_child, second_child 
];
</script>
<style>
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { margin:0; padding:0; }

body { background: #fff; }

/* optional Container STYLES */
.chart { height: 159px; width: 332px; margin: 5px; margin: 5px auto; border: 3px solid #DDD; border-radius: 3px; }
.node { color: #9CB5ED; border: 2px solid #C8C8C8; border-radius: 3px; }
.node p { font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px; height: 20px; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; margin: 0; }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="chart" id="OrganiseChart-simple">
</body>
<script>
new Treant( simple_chart_config );
</script>
</html>
```

Reference URL : https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/

Answer (score -1):

you could try [OrgChart](https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart)

It is opensource and you can checkout a live demo